# you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Match Number' as part of an aggregate

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run this could but the above error message keeps on coming up. I have tried everything and it does not seem to work. Please can anyone help!!!

```
SELECT tblGameResults.MatchNumber,
       Sum(tblPlayerStatistics.Fouls_Made) AS Fouls
FROM tblGameResults 
INNER JOIN tblPlayerStatistics ON tblGameResults.MatchNumber = tblPlayerStatistics.MatchNumber
WHERE (((tblGameResults.Date_Of_Game)=[Date_Of_Game]) 
  AND ((tblGameResults.Place_Of_Game)=[Place_Of_Game]));
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all of your query? It looks as if you might be missing the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` to group the aggregated values under:

```
SELECT 
  tblGameResults.MatchNumber,
  Sum(tblPlayerStatistics.Fouls_Made) AS Fouls
FROM 
  tblGameResults 
INNER JOIN 
  tblPlayerStatistics ON tblGameResults.MatchNumber = tblPlayerStatistics.MatchNumber
WHERE (((tblGameResults.Date_Of_Game)=[Date_Of_Game]) 
  AND ((tblGameResults.Place_Of_Game)=[Place_Of_Game]))
GROUP BY 
  tblGameResults.MatchNumber;
```

Comment: @SchmitzIT: Thanks. I caught it at about the same time your comment appeared. Fixed.

Comment: That was absolultey amazing. It worked perfeclty. However I want it so that at run time it asks me for the date of game and place of game so that for tha game it calculates the total fouls. How would i be able to implement that

Comment: "How would I be able to implement that" Should be able to do (((tblGameResults.Date_Of_Game)=[Enter Date Of Game]) etc for Access.

Comment: @mikeY I have inputtede that after the WHERE so it looks like......... SELECT tblGameResults.MatchID, Sum(tblPlayerStatistics.Fouls_Made) AS Fouls
FROM tblGameResults INNER JOIN tblPlayerStatistics ON tblGameResults.MatchID = tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID
WHERE (((tblGameResults.Date_Of_Game)=[Enter Date Of Game]) 
  AND (((tblGameResults.Place_Of_Game)=[Enter Place Of Game])
GROUP BY tblGameResults.MatchID;......it comes up with syntax error (missing operator)

Comment: @user3407821: That would be a totally separate question, and should therefore be posted as one. The question here was about the error about not having a group by, which I've answered. SO is "one question per post".

Comment: @Ken White I am deeply and very sorry, i am very new to this. I have reposted another question as it is unrelated. I hope you can help. Thank you your help was amazing!!! it worked perfectly!!

Comment: @user3407821: No problem, and no apology needed. :-)